# How to change email settings

Tags: email

Constantly get the error:
Outgoing server (SMTP) smtp.protonmail.com is unknown.
As a newbie, have no idea how this is solved.

How is this solved?

dlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install Proton Bridge...

https://protonmail.com/bridge/

Then you have to configure the mail client...

https://protonmail.com/bridge/thunderbird#1